# How to see changes made by me in merge commit

Tags: git, phpstorm

In git, how can I see changes made **ONLY** by me in last merge commit? to see only lines changed be me, not lines changed by somebody else.

Typically when I push and there is conflict, I do merge and solve some conflicts. After resolving them, I want to review conflict that I've solved. I use:

```
git show HEAD
```

to see last merge commit, it shows some useful information, but it also show changes made by someone else, that do not conflict with my changes. Or my changes, that do not conflict with other person's changes.

example output of git show HEAD:

```
  1.
- 2.
+ 2. zzzz
  3.
  4.
 -5. change A
 +5. change B
  6.
  7.
 -8.
 +8. zzzzzz
  9.
- 10.
+ 10.
```

I see not conflicting changes in lines 2 and 8, that do not interest me that much. And conflicting line 5 that I am **really** interested in.

Ideally I would like to see. What other person has in this line, what I have in this line, and how it was resolved (with name of each person, for example author A: version A, Author B: version B, resolved to X by author A).

And if it is possible, if I could see this in Phpstorm IDE (based on Jetbrains IDEA) or other GUI that highlights changed characters?

example git repo:
https://github.com/LPodolski/git-merge-show-my-changes
(I posted commits with same email, but author's aliases are different, you can see that in your console using git log).

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?

`git log -p --author=<authorname/yourname>`

EDIT: Ok I have long answer:

Since you know the commit with resulted after merging of the things:

**Step 1**: Get the commit hash

`git log  --author=Uday --merges -p -2`

This lists all the commits involved in the merge.
Example output:

```
commit 1c46adfadsf
Merge: 0bfda16 d8340ff
Author: Uday <author@email.com>
Date:   Tue Nov 27 22:30:36 2012 -0700

    Added datasets from others
```

**Step 2**: Then select the hash that commit hashes and see the commits made by other author.. For that you need to do this:

`$ git log <your commit after merge> -p -2`

Example:

`git log d8340ff -p -2`

```
commit d8340ffcac2293a1bd9958278290234724cb099a
Author: Another author <another@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Nov 22 1:34:57 2012 -0700

    commit msg blah blah...


diff --git a/.DS_Store b/.DS_Store
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..bb727a2
Binary files /dev/null and b/.DS_Store differ
diff --git a/Gemfile b/Gemfile
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
index 853b35e..891f41e
--- a/Gemfile
+++ b/Gemfile
@@ -1,12 +1,17 @@
 source 'https://rubygems.org'

-gem 'rails', '3.2.6'
+gem 'rails', '3.2.9'

 # Bundle edge Rails instead:
 # gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
```

by doing this you will know all the changes that they have done...

Comment: unfortunately no, I do not see what happened in merge commit, only that some conflict was resolved, with no diff what happened. At least git show HEAD shows me all changes in conflicting file:

example of output for both commands: http://pastebin.com/7WGAvuzQ

Comment: try this: `$ git diff --ours`

Comment: I get empty out from that command, git show HEAD still displays as in previous pastebin

Comment: You already merged the file or  about to merge the file and got conflicts?

Comment: already merged, exactly in state as in my demo repo: https://github.com/LPodolski/git-merge-show-my-changes